# Is there a way to clear memory with as3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I have an android game built with Flash that works perfect when you play it. When you restart the game after playing for a while, it begins to experience lag. After three or more retries, the game starts to become super laggy. Is there a way I can clear memory on the "You lose" screen? So when the player restarts, he/she will have a refreshed start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to force garbage collection by making sure objects have removed `Event Listeners`, and if the objects causing the most memory leaks/latency are `null`, then you can execute `System.gc()` if for some reason garbage collection doesn't pick them up.

What happens is that removed clips don't immediately get picked up by garbage collection, keeping the RAM from them, so you need to force it.

You can't 'clear' memory, but you can restore memory from objects that take up memory.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811228/adobe-air-garbage-collection-and-system-gc), it is better to let your application free up the space in idle cycles, but it seems you are at a last-resort situation (though it looks like the MovieClips' Events are holding them in the memory).

Comment: So just write that code (System.gc();) in and memory will clear? I also forgot to mention that the movie clips in the game, get removed. Is setting them to null different than removing them?

Comment: @Razer If they're null garbage collection will pick them up, and having them 'removed' doesn't restore the memory, so `System.gc()` should restore the memory from null objects (deleted MovieClips are null)

Comment: @Razer Most likely you don't clear event listeners from those movie clips you remove at game over. Make sure that each event listener you attach to a movie clip is eventually removed, including added to stage, removed from stage, enter frame, mouse events, etc. You can also use weak references when you create an event listener, this will slow your game a bit but will not prevent garbage collection even with a listener not properly removed.

Comment: It looks like only adding System.gc() in the "lose screen" fixes the problem. If I used only this line of code, will I run into any problems, or is forcing garbage collection many times not good?

Comment: @Vesper The game loop event listener is removed. If I removed the mouse event listeners on the movieclips, will the performance after the player loses and restart increase?

Comment: @Razer Likely, since those mouse event listeners are holding the attached MCs in memory.

Comment: @Razer What Vesper says is true, you can avoid System.gc() if you remove all the events from the clip instead.  As I said, System.gc() is a last resort.

Comment: Calling GC just forces the GC to clean up there and then. You should never really need to do this yourself. More importantly, I think it's side stepping the real issue.  A drop in framerate in an AIR app after x events smells very much like listeners not being cleaned up causing code to be run which isn't intended. Calling gc() won't fix that at all. Find out WHY your framerate is dropping then look at possible solutions, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

**Tip #1 : Use Weak References**

Whenever you addEventListener, use "true" in fifth parameter. Any object with weak references can still be collect by Garbage collector even you forgot to do removeEventListener.

```
mc.addEventListener("eventName",doSomething,false,0,true);
```

**Tip #2: dispose BitmapData.**

If you're using a lot of Bitmap (jpg, png, bmp, etc), it might be a good idea to use BitmapData.dispose them when you finish using it. For example

```
class Bullet extends Sprite {

    private var _bmp:Bitmap;

    public function Bullet() {
        //Load
        var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneLoaded, false, 0, true);
        ldr.url = "picture1.jpg";
        ldr.load(ldr);
    }

    private function doneLoaded(evt:Event):void
    {
        //Store loaded content in _bmp
        _bmp = DisplayObject(evt.target.content);
        addChild(_bmp);
    }

    // call this function when you want to destroy this bullet.
    public function unload() {

        _bmp.bitmapData.dispose(); //Dispose BitmapData to release memory.

    }
}
```